# save rman backup log files to networked location

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

Have tried spooling, have tried command line notation: log \\networked_location\rman.log

Nothing works to get rman to save its own log files to a networked location.  can save them online within the db it is backing up, but want to save then with the actual backups that go to a networked location.

11g, using FRA with no catalog.   Just one db to backup, don't feel the need for a catalog.

Windows Scheduler runs the .bat to pick up the .rcv

Anyone know the trick to get rman to reliably place log files onto a networked location?  The obvious does not work....

Appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping that location as a network drive.